# How to remove "isolated" elemenents in a 2D Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, matrix, binary

I am given a matrix which contains ones and zeros(randomly generated).
I want to remove the "isolated" 1-s.

e.g. :

```
1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

should be:

```
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

Every digit 1 which is surrounded by zeroes (diagonal doesn't count) must be changed to 0.

Here is what I have written so far but it doesn't seem to do anything (it prints back the same matrix as before):

```
void deleteIsolatedOnes(int(&digit_grid)[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (digit_grid[i][j]) // if the current element is one
            {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) // top-left corner
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i][j + 1] && !digit_grid[i + 1][j])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 0 && j == GRID_SIZE - 1) // top-right corner
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i][j - 1] && !digit_grid[i + 1][j])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == GRID_SIZE - 1 && j == 0) // bottom-left corner
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i - 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j + 1])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == GRID_SIZE - 1 && j == GRID_SIZE - 1) // bottom-right corner
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i - 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j - 1])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 0) // top row
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i][j - 1] && !digit_grid[i - 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j + 1])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == GRID_SIZE - 1) // bottom row
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i][j - 1] && !digit_grid[i + 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j + 1])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (j == 0) // left column
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i + 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j + 1] && !digit_grid[i - 1][j])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (j == GRID_SIZE - 1) // right column
                {
                    if (!digit_grid[i + 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j - 1] && !digit_grid[i - 1][j])
                    {
                        digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                // for the inner side of the matrix:
                else if (!digit_grid[i + 1][j] && !digit_grid[i - 1][j] && !digit_grid[i][j + 1] && !digit_grid[i][j - 1])
                {
                    digit_grid[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlexFarber "removing one element affects another" — nope, the ones you need to remove do not affect others. they are isolated.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Are you sure the array contains `0` and `1` as opposed to `'0'` and `'1'`?

Comment: @Henrik Yes, it is an integer array

Comment: @YvesDaoust 'Diagonals' means diagonal neighbours here (items next by corners, that is those whose positions differ by +1 or –1 in both directions from the current one), not array's diagonals.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @Toshkuuu You should try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (like [this](https://ideone.com/JizzRR))

Comment: You have not sufficiently defined your requirements. You've just given a single input and output, not defined "isolated", not defined "removed", ...

Comment: @anatolyg So the code works for you but not for me.. I still can't figure out  the problem. Should I post my entire program?

Comment: @Toshkuuu Not the entire program, but please post enough to see the problem reproduced (in your case - include the printing code). Make it possible for people to **copy code from your question into a file, compile and run it, and see the problem**. Make it easy for people, even if you must copy parts of your code into a temporary file. Also, maybe include info on your platform (OS and compiler version).

Comment: @anatolyg So, here it is: https://ideone.com/5Gb0qk It works btw.. The program should be somewhere else.. I will try to find it by myself

Answer (score 1):

So yeah.. I have fixed the problem and I am pretty ashamed to share what was causing it :D

Basically, I had mixed up the indexes for top and bottom rows:

```
!digit_grid[i + 1][j]
```

should be

```
!digit_grid[i - 1][j]
```

for top and the reverse one for bottom...

I am sorry for this mistake and wasting your time :D

Thanks for all advices!

Answer (score 0):

```
bool _checkIsolatedOne(int i, int j, int(&digit_grid)[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE])
{
    bool one_found = false;
    if (i > 0)
        one_found |= digit_grid[j][i - 1];
    if (j > 0)
        one_found |= digit_grid[j - 1][i];
    if (i < GRID_SIZE - 1)
        one_found |= digit_grid[j][i + 1];
    if (j < GRID_SIZE - 1)
        one_found |= digit_grid[j + 1][i];
    return !one_found;
}


void deleteIsolatedOnes(int(&digit_grid)[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE - 1; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE - 1; i++)
            if (digit_grid[j][i] == 1)
            {
                bool isolated = _checkIsolatedOne(i, j, digit_grid);
                if (isolated)
                    digit_grid[j][i] = 0;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be approached by using a convolution matrix from the computer vision field. In short, it consists in sliding a 3x3 window through the matrix and change a single element at a time (the center of the window) depending on the neighbors.

Maybe too convoluted (unintended pun) for a small example like yours, but definitely useful for large scale cases because it can be easily optimized. For an efficient solution, search for "[separable 2D convolution](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/)".

Comment: The convolution kernel here is not separable

Comment: This morphological erosion is indeed similar to a convolution, but it is not separable. You can also use a standard convolution with coefficients 010/101/010, followed by a binarization, but this could be overkill. It is possible to implement it in-place by keeping a "rolling" copy of the two next rows.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[100][100]={0},row, col;
    cin>>row>>col;
    for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            if(!a[i - 1][j] && !a[i][j + 1] && !a[i + 1][j] && !a[i][j - 1])
                a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Check Program's Output](http://ideone.com/bJhKi6)

Comment: *changing one element effects another element* —that's wrong, no one element depends on removing another one.

Comment: Yeah Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: But the program is correct and specify the purpose. Why downvote ?

Comment: I donot know why. Possibly because it does not handle items in the first row and first column (`j==0` or `i==0`) and runs out of bounds by accessing array items in columns `col` and `col+1` and in rows `row` and `row+1`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what i have done. I have taken 2D array from index 1 to row x col to eliminate the conditions I had to apply for each case to make it less complex by stuffing zeroes around the matrix.